# Syntax error, unexpected keyword_class, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm getting

```
$ syntax error, unexpected keyword_class, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
```

in this line

```
$ %li = link_to 'Features', features_path class => ('active' if params[:action] == 'features')%li
```

Comment: Your formatting doesn't look right, but at a minimum features_path_class should be a symbol.

Comment: -1 There was no effort at all put into trying to work out the answer to this very basic question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
%li = link_to 'Features', features_path, :class => ('active' if params[:action] == 'features')
```

- Remove the trailing `%li`.
- I also turned class into a symbol and prepended it with a comma.

**Edit:**

To add the class to the `%li` tag, try this:

```
%li{:class => (params[:action] == 'features' ? 'active' : nil)}
  = link_to 'Features', features_path
```

Comment: Currently, this is adding the styles to an a class"active", do you know if its possible to make the %li the active class?